# How to replace object ID with alias in URL

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

I have just installed keystone.js  and build basic site. 
However I noticed that URL contains the mongoDB ID of length 24. that looks ugly.
Any Idea, how can I change it.

http://localhost:3000/keystone/users/56ed6816491debf405f99be1
http://localhost:3000/keystone/posts/56ed086c4b4ba4f8044bbbe1

I want it to be like 
http://localhost:3000/keystone/users/enraiser
http://localhost:3000/keystone/posts/my-first-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use  auto key  of keystones

```
var Post = new keystone.List('Post', {
    autokey: { path: 'slug', from: 'title', unique: true },map: { name: 'title' },
    defaultSort: '-createdAt'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create auto-incrementing id field:

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/